# Why does constinit allow UB?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, constexpr, constant-expression, constinit

Say I initialize variables like this:

```
#include <cstdint>

constexpr uint16_t a = 65535;
constinit int64_t b = a * a; // warning: integer overflow in expression of type 'int' results in '-131071' [-Woverflow]
constexpr int64_t c = a * a; // error: overflow in constant expression [-fpermissive]
```

Both `b` and `c` produce undefined behavior because of integer overflow.

With `constinit` the variable is constant initialized. Which makes no guarantee about UB.

With `constexpr` the variable is initialized with a constant expression. Constant expression guarantee not to have any UB. So here the signed integer overflow in an error. But the variable is also automatically const.

So how do I best initialize a non-const variable with a constant expression?

Do I have to write

```
constexpr int64_t t = a * a; // error: overflow in constant expression [-fpermissive]
constinit int64_t b = t;
```

or

```
constinit int64_t b = []()consteval{ return a * a; }(); // error: overflow in constant expression
```

every time?

Comment: @273K The aim is not to fix the UB, it's there intentionally as an example with UB. The aim is to have the constinit fail to compile when UB happens.

Comment: use: `1u*a * a`

Comment: @doug that does not initialize `b` with a constant expression.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow promote the warning to a hard error?

Comment: Use lambda? `constinit int64_t b = []() consteval { return a * a; }();`

Comment: @康桓瑋 You aren't evaluation anything there. Until you invoke the lambda there is no `consteval` evaluation and the UB is not triggered.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow "*You aren't evaluation anything there.*" I *do* invoke the lambda.

Comment: @康桓瑋 If you actually do then you get: https://godbolt.org/z/xYznec41d

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow You just use it directly in the constinit assign to b. Skip the first statement.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow Sorry, I was causing the confusion. In my example I forgot to call the lambda and used `auto` without error (obviously). @康桓瑋 adjusted it to their example changing `auto` to the actual type, which gave an error but not the expected one. When actually calling the lambda, no matter whether `auto` is used, GCC behaves correctly and their original example in the comment is also correct.

Comment: @doug Please stop trying to fix the compiler error, that is intientional. Read the question carefully again.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow  Yep, sorry. my bad.

Comment: @user17732522 If you write just the "CWG issue 2543" up as an answer I will accept that. That's exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow I think I already did or what would you like to see changed/added in my answer?

Comment: @user17732522 Just the paragraph on the CWG. Depending on which way the CWG goes the rest becomes obsolete.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow I put the CWG issue paragraph up-front and made it clear that the rest might be obsolete depending on the resolution. It that is not what you wanted, then I am not sure what you mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is related to [CWG issue 2543](https://cplusplus.github.io/CWG/issues/2543.html).

As it stands currently, because the compiler is allowed to replace any dynamic initialization with static initialization if it can and because `constinit` is only specified to enforce "no dynamic initialization", it might still allow an initializer which is not a constant expression (maybe dependent on the interpretation as discussed in the linked issue). `constinit` therefore reflects whether there will actually be initialization at runtime (which is relevant to avoiding dynamic initialization order issues). It does not necessarily reflect whether the initializer is a constant expression.

As stated in the issue description, this is practically not really implementable though because the dynamic/static initialization choice is made too late in the compilation process to always make `constinit` reflect it properly.

With one possible resolution of the issue, the specification of `constinit` might be changed to actually require the variable to be constant-initialized instead of just requiring that there is no dynamic initialization. If that was the resolution taken, then your first example for the initialization of `b` would also require the compiler to diagnose the UB and all of the other solutions would become obsolete.

The issue description doesn't seem to really favor any direction though.

---

For the current situation (and if the resolution is taken in another direction), an alternative to the solutions you gave is:

```
template<typename T>
consteval auto force_compiletime(T&& t) {
    return std::forward<T>(t);
}
```

or

```
template<typename To, typename T>
consteval To force_compiletime2(T&& t) {
    return std::forward<T>(t);
}
```

and then

```
constinit auto t = force_compiletime(static_cast<int64_t>(a * a));
```

or

```
constinit auto t = force_compiletime2<int64_t>(a * a);
```

Note that you need to include the target type in this way in the initializer, otherwise any potentially UB in the conversion will not  be diagnosed. If you don't care about that

```
constinit int64_t t = force_compiletime(a * a);
```

would also be fine.

---

Technically the solution with the `consteval` lambda from your question is ill-formed, no diagnostic required, because the lambda is marked `consteval` but can never produce a constant expression when called. But I would expect any non-malicious compiler to still diagnose such a call.